# IOS database not retrieving data

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I want to display the data in the table from database in the iphone app. I used the following code to execute that. But its not showing the data in the table.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_beaconDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"SELECT vendor_name, enter_message, enter_image FROM beacons WHERE major=%d AND minor=%d", major[indexPath.row], minor[indexPath.row]];

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_beaconDB,
                       query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSString *title = [[NSString alloc]
                              initWithUTF8String:
                              (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(
                                                                 statement, 0)];
            NSString *description = [[NSString alloc]
                            initWithUTF8String:(const char *)
                            sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            cell.title.text = title;
            cell.description.text = description;
        }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(_beaconDB);
}

return cell;
}
```

In the above "major" is a array. I want to get the array value one by one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many rows your function `numberOfRowsInsection` returns? Also don't you think so to put this data retrieval code outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function.

Comment: it returns the number of values in major. And also how to put this retrieval code outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath and display the values in tablecell

Comment: See this tutorial http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/08/how-to-use-sqlite-with-uitableview-in-iphone-sdk/ It'd quite old but helpful.

Comment: This code does not handle errors. At least log the [error message](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue. I have made mistake in the following line.

```
@"SELECT vendor_name, enter_message, enter_image FROM beacons WHERE major=%d AND minor=%d", major[indexPath.row], minor[indexPath.row]];
```

Instead of using `major[indexPath.row]`

I have to use `major[objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]` and also for `minor`